# C# + REST API + HttpClient + Request Tracker

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am testing REST API + HttpClient on C#.
https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST
But I receive error.
Could you help me please.
What is wrong with my test code?

I think problem is with `client.SendAsync(request)`.

Error code from console:

> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage,System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__70]

```
public class TicketSyncronizer
{
    public int ticketId = 0;
    public class RT_Ticket
    {
        public string SendRequest(int ticketId)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://rt.site.com/REST/1.0/");
                //client.TransportSettings.Cookies = new CookieContainer();
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/ticket/" + ticketId.ToString() + "/show");

                Console.WriteLine("request" + request.ToString());
                var formData = new List <KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user", "user1"));  
                formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pass", "pass2"));
                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
                Console.WriteLine("request + l and p" + request.ToString());
                var response = client.SendAsync(request);
                  return "";
            
            }
        }
    }
static void Main()
{
    //int setticketId = 9134141;
    RT_Ticket checkticket = new RT_Ticket();
    checkticket.SendRequest(9134141);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
}
```

Comment: Hi interesting, was there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

What I guess you want to do is:

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

And then changing your method signature to:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest(int ticketId)
```

Comment: This might help understand what's going on: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html